# Making iOS Gallery - UICollectionView reusability

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview

I am new to iOS developing and I am using Swift 3.

In my gallery app when user selects a cell, the picture inside that cell displays in a UIImageView above and the cell itself becomes bordered red to show that it is selected right now. However, when I scroll up or down and as soon as the selected cell is destroyed UICollectionView selects another cell from the visible ones.

I want to know how can I restore the selected state of a cell when it reused and prevent UICollectionView from doing that. In conclusion I want to know how to prevent from cell reusabilities effects on selection state.

Sorry for my bad English, not a native speaker.

Comment: All you have to do is maintain the indexPaths of the selected cells either inside an array or update the model with a key stating that the item is selected and in your `cellForItem` simply check if the array contains that `indexPath` or your model has the appropriate key set. If it doesn't don't show the red border in the else condition as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can either have an array of the images states if it's true then it's selected else it's not and in the

```
  collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

function you check on the state and do the required setup for the cell or you can make the collection view don't reuse the cells by changing the cell identifier dynamically like this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeCircularCollectionViewCell\(indexPath.row)", for: indexPath) as? HomeCircularCollectionViewCell
//setup cell
return cell
 }
```

hope my answer helps you in your problem